# Subtracting the result of one query from that of another in DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2

For School I need to subtract an average of values of a specific subset of entries in a table from the average of all of these values:

I want to subtract

```
SELECT AVG(gehalt) FROM mitarbeiter WHERE personalnummer IN (SELECT personalnummer FROM zertifiziert)
```

From

```
SELECT AVG(gehalt) FROM mitarbeiter
```

---

Individually these statements work but my attempts to subtract them

```
SELECT (SELECT AVG(gehalt) FROM mitarbeiter) - (SELECT AVG(gehalt) FROM mitarbeiter WHERE personalnummer IN (SELECT personalnummer FROM zertifiziert))
```

and

```
SELECT mige-pige AS differenz FROM ((SELECT SUM(gehalt) AS mige FROM mitarbeiter) UNION (SELECT SUM(gehalt) AS pige FROM mitarbeiter WHERE personalnummer IN (SELECT personalnummer FROM zertifiziert)))
```

didn't, with DB2 getting unexpected tokens. I realize that those two are most likely gibberish, what is the right way to do it?

Comment: Your first query is correct I have checked so would you please post which error db2 return . I have checked your first query in SQL Server for testing purpose.

Comment: Thanks for checking!  
  

`DB2 => SELECT (SELECT AVG(gehalt) FROM mitarbeiter) - (SELECT AVG(gehalt) FROM mitarbeiter WHERE personalnummer IN (SELECT personalnummer FROM zertifiziert))  

SQL0104N  Auf "FROM zertifiziert))" folgte das unerwartete Token
"END-OF-STATEMENT".  Zu den mÃ¶glichen Token gehÃ¶ren: "<table_expr>".  
SQLSTATE=42601`  

it's in german but I think it gets the point across

Comment: SQL0104N Auf "FROM zertifiziert))"  ?

Comment: what is this ? is this part of query ?

Comment: Yes, it's the end of the query.
it basically says "after '...zertifiziert))' there was the unexpected Token "END-OF-STATEMENT". Possible tokens would be '<table_expr>'. SQLSTATE=42601"

Comment: SELECT (SELECT AVG(gehalt) FROM mitarbeiter) - (SELECT AVG(gehalt) FROM mitarbeiter WHERE personalnummer IN (SELECT personalnummer FROM zertifiziert)) ! this is right man please check is there any syntax error otherwise as per sql standard this is working thanks

Comment: Alright I'll just send it in like this. Must be a problem with my method of entering it (over SSH on a windows machine) thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.apsg%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_createcte.htm) to first calculate the average, and then use it in your normal query (CTEs are basically inline views):

```
WITH subset (average) AS (
    SELECT AVG(gehalt)
    FROM mitarbeiter 
    WHERE personalnummer IN (
        SELECT personalnummer
        FROM zertifiziert
    )
)

SELECT AVG(gehalt) - (SELECT average FROM subset)
FROM mitarbeiter
```

Also, I think your first query would work, but you don't have a table reference. Unlike SQL Server (where you can do things like `SELECT CURRENT_USER`) or MySQL, you always have to have a reference to a table. In this case, it'd be the [`SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsysdummy1table.htm) table:

```
SELECT (SELECT AVG(gehalt) FROM mitarbeiter)
 - (SELECT AVG(gehalt) 
    FROM mitarbeiter 
    WHERE personalnummer IN (
        SELECT personalnummer 
        FROM zertifiziert))
FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```